# Finding the condition for minimum value of $c$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I need to find the minimum value of $c$,

> If the equation, $\sec\theta+\csc\theta=c$ has two real roots between $0$ and $2\pi$.

**My attempt**:

I converted the trig ratio in terms of sine and cosine and got $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=c\cos\theta\sin\theta$. Squaring this gives a quadratic equation in $\sin2\theta$, $c^2\sin^22\theta-4\sin2\theta-4=0.$ How to proceed further?

Comment: Only two roots ? Even without plotting, you should know the answer. Three or four roots will more interesting.

Comment: Now you have a quadratic equation  where $\sin\theta$ is real , therefore solve for discriminant and roots